# Скрыть меню которое не влезло

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть меню, задача - скрыть пункты которые не влезли в другой контейнер.
на jquery все относительно просто, но вопрос еще в том, как это сделать на vue.js

[image: твизуальное представление задачи]

Answer (score 0):

Спустя некоторое время, нашел то что мне нужно
если кому понадобится, вот :
https://vue-responsive-menu.netlify.app/